# PHP code displayed in browser

Tags: php, html, database, browser

so, I'm working on a databases project, and i'm trying to code incrementally.  the problem is, when i go to test the php in browser, it displays the php code after my use of "->".  the html printing is displayed properly, which is AFTER the point where the -> is.

here is the php:

```
<?php 
    function getGraphicNovel(){ 
        include_once("./connect.php"); 
        $db_connection = new mysqli($SERVER, $USERNAME, $PASSWORD, $DATABASE); 
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { 
            echo("Can't connect to MySQL Server. Error code: " . mysqli_connect_error()); 
            return null; 
        } 
        $stmt = $db_connection->stmt_init(); 
        $returnValue = "invalid"; 
        if($stmt.prepare("select series from graphic_novel_main natural join graphic_novel_misc")) { 
        $stmt->execute(); 
        $stmt->bind_result($series); 
        while ($stmt->fetch()) { 
            echo "<tr><td>" . $series . "</td></tr>";
        }
        $stmt->close(); 
    } 
    $db_connection->close(); 
} 
getGraphicNovel();
?>
```

here is a link to the page.  hopefully it works for people outside the school's network.

http://plato.cs.virginia.edu/~paw5k/cainedb/viewall.html

if anyone knows why this is happening, your input would be great!

as per request:

php -v:

```
PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.14 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Feb 11 2012 06:50:46) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
```

Comment: Are you running this in a website as in http://localhost/myfile.php, or are you simply browsing out on the file system and opening it?  (hint, that second option won't work, and will do exactly what you're describing.  You need a web server to parse the PHP and generate html.)

Comment: Did you save the file as `.php` or `.html`?

Comment: the server is managed by my school, so i have very limited configuration rights.

the php version:
PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.14 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Feb 11 2012 06:50:46) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies

os:
ubuntu 10.04.03 LTS

file saved as .html, but has other html outside the php.

Comment: jumping frog:  what do you mean?  I'm accessing the .html file from my laptop, but I am committing all changes as i make them.  I view the result in a web browser...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like PHP is not working at all. The only reason you are not seeing the first part, is because your browsers is parsing it as if it were an HTML tag.

Comment: you might be right.  ive emailed my professor.  when i put the bit <?php phpinfo(); ?> in my file, nothing was printed...

Comment: @Drake you need to name the file that you upload with the file extension .php, otherwise typically apache will not parse it as php.

Comment: np, still a bit of a newbie here.  to clarify for anybody looking this up later, it was bc the file did not have a .php filename

Comment: @dqhendricks, what do you mean by "PHP is not working"? How to know it is working. I am new with php. I have posted by questing here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33409539/nginx-shows-php-code-instead-of-executing

Answer (score 1):

Your web server is not aware of PHP, which may not even be installed. Therefore, php code is just treated as normal text. Please update your post to tell what server you're using.

Comment: I have similar problem with nginx. Here is my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33409539/nginx-shows-php-code-instead-of-executing Can you help me with  this?