# php Number Times program

Tags: php, html, post, get

PHP Level = beginner

I am trying to write a simple program that displays the number-times of a particular
value when placed in the input box. I have tried to use the post method to do this but each time the program is up running and the submit button is selected, it displays the whole code of the php file 'timescalc.php'. I'll like to know what I am doing wrong, although I know that
the calculations with the if statements might be wrong.

Heres the code

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Number Times</title>
</head>

<body>

 <h1>Number Times Table Calculator</h1>

<form method="post" action="timescalc.php">
 Enter Number : <input type="text" name="number"> <br>
 <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

<?php

$number = $_POST['number'];

if ($number == 2, $number ++2)
{
echo $number . ;
}

else if ($number == 3, $number ++3)
{
echo $number . ;
}

else if ($number == 4, $number ++4)
{
echo $number . ;
}

else if ($number == 5, $number ++5)
{
echo $number . ;
}

else 
{   
echo "pick numbers from 2  to 5 only" ;
}

?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Make sure your file extension is `.php` and if you're running this from your computer, making sure PHP is installed and properly configured. 9 times out of 10, that's what it is. `.php` files are not like `.htm` files where the browser properly outputs it. A browser doesn't need a "parser", it's built-in.

Comment: And you are running a web server and not accessing the file directly in your browser

Comment: @JohnConde so I can't run this program from my browser unless I'm connected to a web server?

Comment: Yes. That web server can be on your computer, though.

Comment: You're in good hands here, moving on...

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP code displayed in browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093271/php-code-displayed-in-browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have numerous syntax errors in your `php` code but they are corrected here, you also need a webserver like [WAMP SERVER](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) to run php code. Good luck coding!

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Number Times</title>
</head>
<body>

 <h1>Number Times Table Calculator</h1>

<form method="post" action="test.php">
Enter Number : <input type="text" name="number"> <br>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

<?php

$number = $_POST['number'];

if ($number == 2)
{
$number = $number * 2;
echo $number ."." ;
}

else if ($number == 3)
{
$number = $number * 3;
echo $number ."." ;
}

else if ($number == 4)
{
$number = $number * 4;
echo $number ."." ;
}

else if ($number == 5)
{
$number = $number * 5
echo $number ."." ;
}

else 
{   
echo "pick numbers from 2  to 5 only" ;
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```