# Nginx shows php code instead of executing

Tags: php, nginx

I have already running app on nginx made in node.js working fine. Now I have to run php app on same nginx. I am writing here my config files herewith for your perusal. When I heat "http://192.168.1.201:3002/" in my chrome/firefox browser it simply show/render all php code instead of execute the code. I am new with php as well as nginx.

***nginx.config***

```
upstream app_stat {
    server 127.0.0.1:3001;  
    keepalive 80;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /home/manish/workspace/statistics;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    access_log /dev/null;
    #error_log  /var/log/stat-error.log;

        # static resources
        location ~ ^/(robots.txt|humans.txt|favicon.ico) {
            root /home/manish/workspace/statistics;
            access_log on;
            expires max;
        }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        root /home/manish/workspace;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location ~ /js/(.*) {
            add_header X-debug-message "A static file was served by pushstate";

            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
            proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy     true;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_pass         http://app_stat;
        }

        location ~ /socket.io/(.*) {
           add_header X-debug-message "A static file was served by pushstate";

            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
            proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy     true;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_pass         http://app_stat;
        }

       location ~ ^/(.+?)(/.*)?$ {
            add_header X-debug-message "A static file was served by pushstate";

            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
            proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy     true;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_pass         http://app_stat;
        }

    location / {
            if ($http_user_agent ~ (Googlebot|google|bing|yandex|msnbot|AltaVista|DuckDuckBot) ) {
               return 403;
            }

                add_header X-debug-message $http_accept;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
                proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy     true;

                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

                proxy_pass         http://app_stat;
    }

}

# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration

server {
    listen 3002;
    listen [::]:3002 ipv6only=on;

    #root /var/www/wagholigav.com/html;
    root /var/www/html/wagholigav/;
    index index.php index.htm index.html;

    server_name 192.168.1.201:3002;

    access_log  /dev/null;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        #proxy_pass http://192.168.1.201;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_buffering off;
        }

        #location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    location ~/.php$ {
        #try_files $uri =404;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

        #proxy_pass http://192.168.1.201;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
                return 404;
            }

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        include fastcgi_params; 
        #include fastcgi.conf;
    }
}
```

***index.php*** at root directory

```
<?php 
    header('Location:Website/index.php');
?>
```

***index.php*** at Website directory

```
<?php 
        header("Location:home.php");
?>
```

***home.php***

```
<?php 
    include("../conn.php");
    $date=date("Y-m-d");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <title>Home</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animations.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.migrate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.imagesloaded.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/retina-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins-scroll.js"></script>
    <!-- SLIDER REVOLUTION 4.x SCRIPTS  -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins-scroll.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body><div id="top"></div>
        <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="chromeframe">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">activate Google Chrome Frame</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->



<section id="topline" class="color_section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p><i class="rt-icon-mail3"></i> contact@website.com | 
        <a class="socialico-facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/1417595XXXXXX" title="Facebook">#</a>
          </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p class="text-right"><i class="rt-icon-location"></i> City</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>        
</section> 

<section id="header" class="bg-color0">
    <div class="container"><div class="row">

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#top"><img src="example/logo1.png" height="50px" width="50px" alt=""> वाघोली ग्रामस्थ मंडल</a>

      <div class="col-sm-12 mainmenu_wrap"><div class="main-menu-icon visible-xs"><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>
        <ul id="mainmenu" class="nav menu sf-menu responsive-menu superfish">
          <li class="">
            <a href="#features">features</a>
          </li>
          <li class="">
            <a href="#title_about">about</a>
          </li>
          <li class="">
            <a href="#portfolio">portfolio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="">
            <a href="#team">team</a>
          </li>

          <li class="">
            <a href="#contact">contact</a>
          </li>
         </ul>
      </div>

    </div></div>
</section>


<section id="mainslider">
  <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <div class="responisve-container">
        <div class="slider">
        <!--  <div class="fs_loader"></div>-->
          <div class="slide">
            <img src="example/home_1.JPG" alt="" width="1920" height="550" data-position="0,0" data-in="fade" data-delay="0" data-out="fade">
          </div>
          <div class="slide" data-in="slideLeft">
            <img src="example/home_2.JPG" alt="" width="1920" height="550" data-position="0,0" data-in="fade" data-delay="0" data-out="fade">
          </div>
          <div class="slide" data-in="slideLeft">
            <img src="example/home_3.jpg" alt="" width="1920" height="550" data-position="0,0" data-in="fade" data-delay="0" data-out="fade">
           </div>
          <div class="slide" data-in="slideLeft">
            <img src="example/home_4.jpg" alt="" width="1920" height="550" data-position="0,0" data-in="fade" data-delay="0" data-out="fade">
           </div>
            <div class="slide" data-in="slideLeft">
            <img src="example/home_5.JPG" alt="" width="1920" height="550" data-position="0,0" data-in="fade" data-delay="0" data-out="fade">
           </div>
            <div class="slide" data-in="slideLeft">
            <img src="example/home_6.jpg" alt="" width="1920" height="550" data-position="0,0" data-in="fade" data-delay="0" data-out="fade">
           </div>
            <div class="slide" data-in="slideLeft">
            <img src="example/home_7.jpg" alt="" width="1920" height="550" data-position="0,0" data-in="fade" data-delay="0" data-out="fade">
           </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>


<div id="box_wrap">

<section id="features" class="color_section">
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 text-center">
              <p>Some code</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
             <h2 class="block-header">History</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3 text-center">
              <p>Some code2</p>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 text-center">
             &nbsp;
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
             <p style="margin-top:-25px;">Area Country</p>
             <hr>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3 text-center">
              &nbsp;
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">

          <div class="block widget_accordion">
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <div style="font-size:16px;" class="accordion-toggle collapsed" >
                        some text content 
                    </div>
                  </h4>
                </div>
             </div>

             <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <div style="font-size:16px;" class="accordion-toggle collapsed" >
                        some text content2
                    </div>
                  </h4>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <div style="font-size:16px;" class="accordion-toggle collapsed" >
                        some text content3
                    </div>
                  </h4>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <div style="font-size:16px;" class="accordion-toggle collapsed" >
                        some text content4
                    </div>
                  </h4>
                </div>
              </div>

          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-5">
                &nbsp;  
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
                <a href="history.php" target="_blank" class="theme_btn">read more...</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="title_section" id="title_about">
  <div class="container">

<div class="row">  
  <div class="col-lg-6">
  <div style="font-size:24px;color:#000;">Event</div></br>
      <?php $estr="SELECT * FROM `event_tbl` WHERE `edate`>='$date' ORDER BY `eid` DESC limit 5";
            $estr1=mysql_query($estr) or die(mysql_error());
            while($efa=mysql_fetch_array($estr1))
            {
            ?>
      <h4> <a href="sevent.php?eid=<?php echo $efa['eid'];?>" target="new"><?php echo $efa['ename'];?></a></h4>
      <p><?php  $s=$efa['edesc'];$s1=substr($s,0,100);echo $s1;?></p>
    <?php   } ?>
    </div>

   <div class="col-lg-6">
   <div style="font-size:24px;color:#000;">Past Event</div></br>
      <?php $estr="SELECT * FROM `event_tbl` WHERE `edate`<'$date' ORDER BY `eid` DESC limit 5";
            $estr1=mysql_query($estr) or die(mysql_error());
            while($efa=mysql_fetch_array($estr1))
            {
            ?>
      <h4> <a href="sevent.php?eid=<?php echo $efa['eid'];?>" target="new"><?php echo $efa['ename'];?></a></h4>
      <p><?php  $s=$efa['edesc'];$s1=substr($s,0,100);echo $s1;?></p>
    <?php   } ?>
    </div>

  </div></br></br>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
                &nbsp;  
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
                <a href="events.php" class="theme_btn" target="new">read more...</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="portfolio" class="fullwidth_portfolio grey_section">
    <div class="container"><div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
          <h2 class="block-header">Gallary</h2>
          <p>Watch more<a class="socialico-facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/141759572XXXXXX" title="Facebook"> इथे </a> Click here | </p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div id="portfolio_wrapper">
      <ul class="items-row row cols-3 portfolio filtrable clearfix isotope" id="portfolioContainer">

<?php $gstr="SELECT * FROM `event` WHERE `edate`>='$date' ORDER BY `eid` DESC limit 8";
            $gstr1=mysql_query($gstr) or die(mysql_error());
            while($gfa=mysql_fetch_array($gstr1))
            {
            ?>

        <li class="item isotope-item">
          <div class="portfolio_item_image">
            <?php $gifa=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `imgs` where eventid=".$gfa['eid']." ORDER BY `eventid` ASC"));?>
             <a href="./gshow.php?eid=<?php echo $gfa['eid'];?>" target="new"><img alt="" src="<?php echo $gifa['imgpath'];?>" ></a>
          </div>
          <div class="item_title">
            <h4>
              <a href="./gshow.php?eid=<?php echo $gfa['eid'];?>"  target="new"><?php echo $gfa['ename']; ?></a>
            </h4>
          </div>
        </li>
        <?php   } ?>
         <li class="item isotope-item">
              <div class="portfolio_item_image">
                 <img alt="" src="example/64.jpg" ></a>
              </div>
              <div class="item_title">
                <h4>
                 photo
                </h4>
              </div>
            </li>

            <li class="item isotope-item"> 
              <div class="portfolio_item_image">
                <img alt="" src="example/74.jpg" >           
              </div>
              <div class="item_title">
                <h4>
                  Photo
              </div>     
            </li>

      </ul>
</br></br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-5">
                &nbsp;  
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
                <a href="gallery.php" target="_blank" class="theme_btn">Read more...</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
  </br>
  </br>
</section>

<section id="team" class="">
  <div class="container">

  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
          <h2 class="block-header">member</h2>
          <p>
            content  content content content
      </p>
      </div>
  </div>
    <div class="accordion-box ">
        <?php $kstr="SELECT * FROM `kamiti_tbl` GROUP BY `kstatus` ORDER BY `kstatus` DESC";
              $kstr1=mysql_query($kstr) or die(mysql_error());
              while($kfa=mysql_fetch_array($kstr1))
              {?>
        <div class="accord-elem ">
            <div class="accord-title">
                <a class="accord-link" href="#"></a>
                <h2>कमिटी मेंबर (<?php echo $kfa['kyear']?>) ते आजपर्यंत)  </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="accord-content">
            <?php $mstr="SELECT * FROM `kamiti` where `kstatus`=".$kfa['kstatus'];
                    $mstr=mysql_query($mstr) or die(mysql_error());
                    while($mfa=mysql_fetch_array($mstr))
                    {?>

                <div class="block col-md-3 col-sm-6" style="margin-top:25px;">
                    <center>
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="<?php echo $mfa['kimg'];?>" alt="team" style="width:130px;height:150px;">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4><?php echo $mfa['kname'];?></h4>
                                <p><?php echo $mfa['kdp'];?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </center>
                </div>

            <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
<section id="contact" class="darkgrey_section parallax">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
        <h2 class="block-header">contact</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="contact-form">
          <form method="get" action="sendmail.php">
            <p class="contact-form-name">
              <label for="name">Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
              <input type="text"  size="30" value="" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" required />
            </p>
             <p class="contact-form-email">
              <label for="email">Phone Number <span class="required">*</span></label>
              <input type="text" aria-required="true" size="30" value="" name="mo" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" required>
            </p>
            <p class="contact-form-email">
              <label for="email">Email <span class="required">*</span></label>
              <input type="email" aria-required="true" size="30" value="" name="em" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
            </p>
            <p class="contact-form-message">
              <label for="message">Comment</label>
              <textarea aria-required="true" rows="5" cols="45" name="msg" id="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
            </p>
            <p class="contact-form-submit text-center vertical-margin-81">
              <input type="submit" value="Send" name="send" class="theme_btn">
            </p>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="block widget_text col-sm-3">
        <p>some text content<br> 
          some text content<br> 
          <span><strong> Mr X   - </strong> </span>9999999<br>
          <span><strong>Mr y   - </strong> </span>888888<br>
          <span><strong>Email:</strong> </span>
          <a href="mailto:info@company.com">contact@website.com</a><br> 

        </p>
        <p>
          <a class="socialico-facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/141759572XXXXXX" title="Facebook">#</a>
          </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

</div><!-- EOF #box_wrap -->

<div id="gallery_container"></div>
        <script src="js/vendor/respond.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/placeholdem.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/hoverIntent.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/superfish.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/jquery.actual.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/jquery.elastislide.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/jquery.ui.totop.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/jquery.easypiechart.min.js"></script>
        <script src='js/vendor/jflickrfeed.min.js'></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/jquery.sticky.js"></script>
        <script src='js/vendor/owl.carousel.min.js'></script>
        <script src='js/vendor/jquery.nicescroll.min.js'></script>
        <script src='js/vendor/jquery.fractionslider.min.js'></script>
        <script src='js/vendor/jquery.scrollTo-min.js'></script>
        <script src='js/vendor/jquery.localscroll-min.js'></script>
        <script src='js/vendor/jquery.parallax-1.1.3.js'></script>

        <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>

         <!-- Map Scripts -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't understand, where is the problem? can some one guide where to find/look? I had read several articles/blogs on stackoverflow and internet, but still not getting any solution. 
Thanks.

***EDIT on 5th Nov 2015 :***

Now I am getting error on browser is "No input file specified.", where as my nginx error log has following error :

```
FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Success in Unknown on line 0
Unable to open primary script: [path] (Success)" while reading response header from upstream
```

and nginx access log has this error :

```
GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 56 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)
```

Comment: Do you have PHP installed? Nginx is not configured to render PHP. [This](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/) should help.

Comment: To me, this sounds like oyu don't have PHP installed. Webservers can't run this natively.

Comment: I have installed PHP

Comment: I have already installed PHP @Satisfaction,  y-u-no-work

Comment: @Satisfaction, I am looking into your given reference. But as I told you, I am new with nginx, so not getting idea in a first look, let me understand

Comment: Refer this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/134666/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-enable-php-on-nginx

Comment: @GauravDave, my config looks like as your reference, still problem occures

Comment: When you change config, do you restart nginx?

Comment: yes @GauravDave sir. Please have a look at my nginx.config      location ~/.php$ {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
                    return 404;
                }

                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_nam$

                include fastcgi_params;
        }

Comment: only change is :  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

Comment: Do you have access to error log, that files basically hold information regarding error message? If you have access then you might get some information, other thing is, when you do php -v in your terminal, what do you see?

Comment: @GauravDave, here is my php version : PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 (cli) (built: Oct 28 2015 01:34:46) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies, and nothing is record in nginx error log.

Comment: @GauravDave, and don't know about php error log, if any

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93684/discussion-between-gaurav-dave-and-manish-sapkal).

Comment: Have you try to install php-fpm ? Nginx doesn't understand php natively

Answer (score 0):

How about adding index.php here? Line 11.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /home/manish/workspace/statistics;
    index **index.php** index.html index.htm;
```