# Why php code shows in browser?

Tags: php, node.js, nginx

I have installed node.js and nginx for my web app development, is working fine. Now I have to develop php website with nginx. I have installed php5-fpm on my Ubuntu 14.01 machine, and create one sample index.html and index.php in 'var/www/html/test/' directory. When I enter url for .html page (e.g. '192.168.1.201:3001/index.html', it's looks perfect. but when enter url for .php (e.g. '192.168.1.201:3001/index.php') is shows me code instead of running code. 
Here is output in my browser :

```
<?php
  phpinfo( );
?>
```

I have posted my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33409539/nginx-shows-php-code-instead-of-executing) with details. 
I don't know, why is this happens. No errors logs in nginx or php5fpm. Where to find proble?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nginx shows php code instead of executing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33409539/nginx-shows-php-code-instead-of-executing)

Comment: @JamesFenwick Yes It is. I have mention here. I am a new bee, and does not know where to look? It seems php-fpm not parsing code.

Comment: There is no point asking a duplicate question, it will just be closed. I would try to improve the quality of your original question, e.g. reduce the code block to a simple example to make it easier to read, and you will be more likely to get an answer there.

Comment: Thanks @JamesFenwick, As you know I have posted question 6 days ago, but no one replying, that's why I am posted duplicate. I am also new with stackoverflow.

Comment: @JamesFenwick, Now I am getting error on html page "No input file specified.". my nginx error log shows me this error : "FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Success in Unknown on line 0
Unable to open primary script: [path] (Success) while reading response header from upstream" and nginx access.log shows me "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 56 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)" Any Idea sir